# How $_GET works in this script

Tags: php

I am going through this pagination script and i cannot understand how $_GET is being used.This is the script

```
<?php
$host = "localhost";
    $user = "root";
    $password = "";
    $database = "world";

    $db = mysql_connect($host, $user, $password);
    if($db)
    {
        $select_db = mysql_select_db($database);
        if(!$select_db)
        {
            echo 'Database Error:'. mysql_error();
        }
    }else
    {
        echo 'Connection Error:'. mysql_error();
    }
$rowsPerPage = 15;

// by default we show first page
$pageNum = 1;

// if $_GET['page'] defined, use it as page number
if(isset($_GET['page']))
{
echo 'not set';
$pageNum = $_GET['page'];
}
else{echo 'is set';}
// counting the offset
$offset = ($pageNum - 1) * $rowsPerPage;

$query = "select * from city" .
" LIMIT $offset, $rowsPerPage";
//print $query;
$result=mysql_query($query);
?>
```

I named the script p.php.

This script works although the script do not have a query string that has `?page=n`

I tried executing this script named tr.php

```
if(isset($_GET['tr']))
{
echo "not set <br/>";
}
else{echo 'is set <br/>'; }

if(empty($_GET['tr'])){
echo 'so not there <br/>';
}
```

and i got this

```
is set
so not there
```

Why is $_GET; acting like this?.

Comment: try accessing your script with `?tr=blah`

Comment: What is the query string showing at your address bar ?

Comment: I don't know what the question is. What exactly don't you understand about "how it's being used"?

Comment: Your logic is bad: `if (isset($_GET['tr'])) { echo 'not set'; // but it is set }`, and in the second if you're using `$GET` instead of `$_GET`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because you are checking your `isset()` in the opposite way

```
if(isset($_GET['page']))
{
    echo 'not set';
```

Here you are using isset and checking if it is true, which is it, so you print `not set` while it is actually set

```
if(isset($_GET['page'])) {
    echo 'is set';
    $pageNum = $_GET['page'];
} else {
    echo 'not set';
}
```

As side not i'd like to tell you that `mysql_*` function are actually deprecated and no longer manteined so you really should switch either to [`mysqli`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [`PDO`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php)

Answer (score 1):

The strings says the wrong things. It is clearly a mistake. It makes a whole lot more sense if you just flip your strings around.

```
if(isset($_GET['tr']))   // This means it IS set...
{
    echo "IS set <br/>";    // ...thus, we change this....
}
else
{
    echo 'is NOT set <br/>';    // ... and this.
}

if(empty($GET['tr'])){
    echo 'so not there <br/>';
}
```